# How to remember the word Veteran

Tags: difference

Today is Veterans' day.

Look up the [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/veteran):

> c. 1500, "old experienced soldier," from French *vétéran*, from Latin *veteranus*... from *vetus* (genitive *veteris*) "old, aged, advanced in years; of a former time," as a plural noun, *vetores*, "men of old, forefathers," from PIE **wet-es-*, from root **wet-* (2) "year" (source also of Sanskrit *vatsa-* "year," Greek *etos* "year," Hittite *witish* "year," Old Church Slavonic *vetuchu* "old," Old Lithuanian *vetušas* "old, aged;" and compare **[wether](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wether?ref=etymonline_crossreference)**).

Vetus has no similarities with old or aged.

How could remember the word?

Comment: What do you mean by "no similarities"? The entry you drew from does not say that it shares etymological roots with "old" or "aged". What do you mean by "How to remember" and "How could remember"? Do you mean "How can one account for"? Or are you asking for a mnemonic for memorizing the word or its meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the root meaning of a word may give you some idea of past use, but language evolves, so don't expect it always to make things clearer.

In this case though, it seems perfectly understandable. The root meaning of 'veteran' means 'old', and with age comes experience. Maybe you've heard the expression '*an old hand*', meaning someone who has considerable experience of something.

You can be a veteran of anything, but a *war veteran* is the word's most common use, and so is often used in isolation. When you hear someone is a "veteran", one tends to assume they are a war veteran.

I don't know if that will help you *remember* the word, but hopefully goes some way to explaining it.

Maybe this poem will help:

> **"Veteran"**
>   I come from the Latin *veteranus*
>   which you'll know if you're no ignoramus
>   Those Romans knew that age means knowledge,
>   the kind you can't learn in a college
>   Experience of something, often extensive,
>   in this case, it can make one quite pensive
>   A 'veteran' or 'vet' is a veteran of *war*
>   and their experience, the horrors that they saw.

Comment: I understand your intent, but I regard the word "veteran" without a qualifier as *military* veteran, which may or may not be the same as *war* veteran.  It is possible to have served in the military without that service being during a period of war nor involving combat duties.  The person who served is still a veteran.

Comment: @cobaltduck I understand your intent too, but the question wasn't about the difference between a military veteran and a war veteran - just why we use the word veteran. I *did* assume that it was about war veterans, but that's because I'm British English, and we don't have "veterans day" - the 11th November is *Remembrance Day* and it is entirely about remembering the fallen in wars.

Comment: In the US we have Memorial Day for fallen war veterans, and Veteran's Day is simply for appreciation of our active duty military and veterans.